# "WITH x AS " ParseException Error in DataBricks notebook

Tags: sql, databricks, parseexception

I'm trying to JOIN two tables in a DataBricks Notebook. The first line in the SQL statement is erroring-out.

I can't determine why. The docs I've read say its typically due to a typo. But that is not the case for me (at least not that I can see).

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'WITH mgt '(line 1, pos 8)

== SQL ==
WITH xxx AS(
--------^^^
```

Comment: can you share the full statement that caused this error?

Comment: I *could* share an anonymized query, but the error is on line 1, position 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by characters that look like ordinary space (0x20), but are something different. Unicode has [quite a lot of them](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) and it happens, especially on copy-paste, that some weird formatting corrupts SQL query string.

For example:

```
val sql = "WITH mgt AS(select 1) select * from mgt"
spark.sql(sql)

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'WITH mgt '(line 1, pos 8)

== SQL ==
WITH mgt AS(select 1) select * from mgt
--------^^^
```

Why did that occur? We can discover by looking at exact byte representation of SQL:

```
sql.getBytes("utf-8").map("%02X".format(_)).mkString
57495448206D6774E2808041532873656C6563742031292073656C656374202A2066726F6D206D6774
                ^^^^^^
```

Marked sequence is `0xE28080` - which is [En Quad](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2000), not a space. You can backspace it and type again to fix it.

Comment: Excellent answer. This was indeed the issue. Thank you for the addition validation step using `sql.getBytes()` too!